# $D(A)\supset$ $D$ $(A-${$x$}) also holds? ($D(A)$ is the derived set if $A$.)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

We have,$x\in D(A)\implies x$ is a limit point of $A\implies$every nbd $N$ of $x$ contains a point of $A$ other than $x\implies$ every nbd $N$ of $x$ contains a point of $A-${$x$} other than $x\implies x$ is a limit point of $A-${$x$}$\implies x \in $ $ D(A-${$x$}$) $,Therefore,$D(A)\subset$ $D$ $(A-${$x$}).

My question is does $D(A)\supset$ $D$ $(A-${$x$}) also holds?I need to prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written isn't correct, since you don't know that the point $x$ you are testing for membership in $D(A)$ is the same as the point you removed from $A$ to get $A-\{x\}$.  However, if you change the point you're testing to $y$, then the converse of each your steps holds trivially, so you can reverse your argument to prove that $D(A)\supseteq D(A-\{x\})$.

(The step "every neighborhood $N$ of $y$ contains a point of $A$ other than $y$ $\implies$ every neighborhood $N$ of $y$ contains a point of $A-\{x\}$ other than $y$" in the forward direction requires some more justification, and may or may not be true depending on exactly what sort of space you're talking about.)

Comment: Eric Wofsey:Means the result holds generally?

Comment: @PKStyles, I believe he means your argument is $\iff.$

Comment: @Eric Wofsey:At first i also checked that reverse of my argument is holding,but my professor asked for a try to have a counterexample but i could'nt find any that's why i asked this.